# Load Repast Model from freeze dry

Tags: repast-simphony

A simple question. I have model which is very costly to initialize but much lighter to run. There is the option to freeze dry the model after initialisation in the gui. However, I could not figure out how to load the freezed dry model in the gui or in the batch gui. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

I freezed dry the initalized model but could not figure a way to load the model state

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the Data Loaders element in the Scenario Tree and "set data loader", you should see an option for loading from the freeze dried model. I think the XML format is the one you want.